# Centos 6 / Postgres 9.3 periodic "pauses"

Tags: postgresql, linux, memory, performance, centos, postgresql-performance

Multiple times a day we experience "pauses" on our Postgres server of about 10-20 seconds where kernel CPU usage is high and everything else grinds to a halt.  At the Postgres level this results in queries that usually take ~50 milliseconds taking ~15 seconds to complete.  I/O is not especially high leading up to or during these periods, however when the "pause" concludes there's a spike of I/O as all the backlogged queries execute at once.

To help diagnose what's happening I set "vmstat" to run continuously and was able to capture data during one of the "pauses".  It is below followed by some observations:

```
procs -----------memory---------------  ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------ ---timestamp---
  r  b   swpd    free   buff     cache   si   so    bi    bo    in    cs us sy id wa st
  1  1 619800 3244716 331608 247468480    0    0    40  3292 10574  7972 10  1 88  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:00 CST
  0  1 619800 3241500 331616 247468496    0    0   228  2128  9780  7255 11  1 87  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:01 CST
  1  0 619800 3233564 331616 247468768    0    0    96  5240 10989  7899 12  3 83  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:02 CST
  2  0 619800 3222960 331616 247469008    0    0   444  1776  8987  6882  9  1 88  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:03 CST
  4  0 619800 3211324 331616 247469392    0    0   160  2928 11020  8041 13  1 84  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:04 CST
  1  0 619800 3208224 331616 247469984    0    0   432  2192 13263  9181 13  1 84  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:05 CST
  6  0 619800 3017956 331624 247472976    0    0   272  2672 11933 10566 12  3 83  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:06 CST
  2  0 619800 2927000 331624 247470352    0    0   224 11984 16976 11926 23  3 65  9  0 2016-12-10 10:13:07 CST
  1  0 619800 2912128 331628 247470784    0    0    96  2596 11624  2844  5  9 86  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:08 CST
  9  0 619800 2883584 331628 247470848    0    0   216   416 16335  2889  4 49 47  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:09 CST
  5  0 619800 2818552 331628 247471280    0    0   368  1424 17922  6836 24 22 53  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:10 CST
 95  2 619800 2760056 331640 247471600    0    0   184  2248 23144  2407  3 63 34  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:12 CST
 16  0 619800 2645296 331640 247471616    0    0    16  1308 21725  3390 18 70 11  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:13 CST
 81  1 619800 2600152 331640 247474608    0    0    32   732 26260  1833  3 82 15  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:15 CST
 29  0 619800 2595524 331640 247471712    0    0     0   160 14164   969  3 90  7  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:16 CST
 89  0 619800 2552344 331640 247471712    0    0    16   208 16366  3239  5 73 22  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:17 CST
 81  1 619800 2446032 331656 247473840    0    0     0  3552 20724  9294 22 67 11  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:18 CST
 31  0 619800 2431720 331656 247474304    0    0     8   712 14404  1875  8 90  2  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:19 CST
 90  0 619800 2396932 331656 247471424    0    0   168   280 17779  2529  6 75 19  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:20 CST
218  1 619800 2338236 331664 247472000    0    0     8   164 17665   894  7 89  1  3  0 2016-12-10 10:13:21 CST
 24  0 619800 2238648 331672 247472256    0    0   328  3008 26926  4552 13 58 29  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:23 CST
 13  0 619800 2180636 331676 247472480    0    0     0   872 15782  2571 17 45 34  4  0 2016-12-10 10:13:24 CST
 58  0 619800 2103736 331676 247472608    0    0     8   432 19797  3034 14 62 24  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:25 CST
230  1 619800 2031848 331676 247475616    0    0   104   176 17259  2172 15 72 12  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:26 CST
 73  0 619800 1944576 331684 247472752    0    0     8   732 20678  5133 27 72  1  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:27 CST
 11  0 619800 1874744 331684 247472320    0    0    72  3840 18696 12091 27 36 35  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:28 CST
 30  0 619800 1640572 331688 247472912    0    0    76  2984 30941 10846 65 28  7  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:29 CST
 18  0 619800 1419204 331688 247473376    0    0   592  2592 29684 11706 48 30 22  0  0 2016-12-10 10:13:30 CST
 16  0 619800 1286564 331688 247473472    0    0   320  4472 29114 16349 35 19 44  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:31 CST
 19  0 619800 1040148 331692 247474240    0    0   488  4980 31327 17965 54 23 21  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:32 CST
  5  0 619800  865284 331692 247475056    0    0   768 13144 23288 13467 33 20 38  8  0 2016-12-10 10:13:33 CST
  8  1 621296 3469752 331424 244810800    0 1496   856  7408 31176 13778 32 10 54  4  0 2016-12-10 10:13:34 CST
  6  1 621328 4088624 331420 244119216    0   32   844  4324 24021 14942 37  6 54  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:35 CST
 17  0 621328 4053912 331420 244120192    0    0   128  3280 35276 13734 30 31 37  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:36 CST
 23  1 621328 4008996 331424 244120384    0    0   808  2716 37153  8831 38 46 14  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:37 CST
 11  0 621324 3928588 331424 244126144   16    0  3180  7928 23629 11140 30 17 48  5  0 2016-12-10 10:13:38 CST
  4  0 621324 3922964 331424 244124288    8    0    32  3640 19315 12297 25  6 68  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:39 CST
  3  0 621324 3998812 331428 244124160    0    0   452  6944 16584 12847 19  2 77  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:40 CST
  2  0 621324 3970896 331428 244124640    0    0   192  2688 15078 11150 17  2 80  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:41 CST
  5  1 621324 4052340 331428 244124928    0    0   208  3040 14187 10789 16  2 81  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:42 CST
  0  0 621324 4050172 331432 244125760    0    0   768  3828 13099 10432 15  2 81  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:43 CST
  5  1 621324 4000196 331432 244126016    0    0   712  5448 19467 12603 30  2 66  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:44 CST
  3  0 621324 4010152 331436 244126976    0    0   684  3140 11787  8044  9  1 89  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:45 CST
  6  0 621324 3992764 331436 244130016    0    0   316  2384 12966 13207 14  3 82  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:46 CST
  0  0 621324 3985352 331436 244127776    0    0   176  2512 13597 19701 12  5 82  1  0 2016-12-10 10:13:47 CST
  3  2 621324 4101460 331440 244128112    0    0   152  4796 11566  8410 15  2 82  2  0 2016-12-10 10:13:48 CST
  1  1 621324 4132160 331440 244129248    0    0  1128  3320 12961 10122 16  2 79  3  0 2016-12-10 10:13:49 CST
```

During the affected period:

1. The # of processes waiting to run is much higher than normal.
2. The # of blocks read and written is much lower than normal.
3. System CPU % is much higher than normal.
4. Free memory decreases steadily (and was already decreasing prior to the affected period), bottoms out, then goes back up.
5. Just after free memory bottoms out there's some swapping that occurs, which is not typical.

Also, it seems noteworthy that there are no entries at 10:13:11, 10:13:14 and 10:13:22.  So the vmstat process itself wasn't even able to run during those periods in order to output stats.

Can you think of what might cause this behavior, or future avenues of investigation?

I checked /var/log/messages and didn't see anything during the affected period:

```
[root@hostname ~]# egrep "Dec 10 10:1[234]" /var/log/messages
Dec 10 10:12:36 hostname rgmanager[14302]: [script] Executing /etc/init.d/postgresql-cluster status
Dec 10 10:13:06 hostname rgmanager[14827]: [script] Executing /etc/init.d/postgresql-cluster status
Dec 10 10:13:36 hostname rgmanager[15495]: [script] Executing /etc/init.d/postgresql-cluster status
Dec 10 10:14:06 hostname rgmanager[15958]: [script] Executing /etc/init.d/postgresql-cluster status
Dec 10 10:14:37 hostname rgmanager[16540]: [script] Executing /etc/init.d/postgresql-cluster status
```

Additionally, the last entries in dmesg are from several days ago.

Comment: Is this on a physical server, a VM on your own hardware, or a VM in "the cloud"?

Comment: Are you logging checkpoints? For debugging, set `log_checkpoints=on` to see if there is any correlation with your "stuck" processes. Also, if you if you haven't already, try enabling checkpoint smoothing via `checkpoint_completion_target=0.9`

Comment: Bare metal, not a VM.  Though, the host is part of a Redhat cluster.  Currently Postgres just runs on one node; the other is for redundancy.  Yes, we're logging checkpoints.  Nothing seems to correlate in the Postgres logs, other than a bunch of long-running queries (that shouldn't ever be long-running, e.g. Postgres querying its own internal tables).

Comment: With system times so high, on a database, i suggest you to verify and eventually disable "transparent huge pages" of redhat. Probably not THE problem, but possibly A big problem.

Comment: Thanks, will check.  Worth noting:  system cpu only goes above 5% during these episodes.  The rest of the time its negligible.  My only theory is that something starts eating up the free memory (which is small, since most memory is used to cache disk), and when free mem gets dangerously low Centos isn't able to reclaim memory from the cache quickly enough and so has to swap stuff to disk.  Maybe a bad theory.

Comment: THP is enabled.  Will disable it when I get permission and report back.

Comment: @jph did disabling THP help?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to update this.  Yes, it completely fixed the issue.  If user_0 (or you) want to add it as an answer I'll mark as correct.